# Is that fair to delete my comments only?

Tags: discussion, deleted-comments

I posted an answer to this question: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/14569797#14569797)

Here is my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14569797/1646111

Today I just noted that my comments were deleted, I got a copy from Google Cache:
[image]

**Now became:**
[image]

Is that fair? I hope someone guide me to right direction. I am really upset with this because in science, stating an argument without reference is nothing, here I see that my arguments that are based on reference are nothing...

Comment: Ad-hominem attacks like "you are not academic person, and not professional" are generally not a good idea.

Comment: In addition to Oden's points; remember that comments are supposed to be temporary. I'm sure lots of my comments have been removed because while useful at the time they are now obsolete. Expect comments to be deleted at any time for any reason. N.B. I'm not entirely sure your comments were ever that useful but even if they are expect them to go

Comment: Also: as much as you'd like: [SO] is not about science. It's about professionals, but that's not always the same. And "BAD" and "GOOD" *are* valid when talking about professional ways to solve a problem.

Comment: Just to add - comments by other people were also removed. Your's were not singled out. Also seen in your screenshots (last comment isn't there and is not yours)

Comment: @JoachimSauer: that based on argument that he said (good or bad) for an answer which must not be, scientific judgment based on (correct, incorrect, valid, invalid, etc) with arguments.

Comment: @Akam: well, the "GOOD/BAD" part is hardly why your comment was removed, so it's probably not relevant to this discussion. Sorry for bringing it up at all.

Answer (score 15):

I deleted your comments, and in general, deleted any of the comments that I felt like didn't add value to the conversation.

I spent a lot of time looking through all the posts on that question to make sure to get any comments deleted that I feel like should have been deleted.

I also deleted some other people's comments, as this image shows:

[image]

I remove comments for a lot of reasons:

- If I agree with the comment flag
- If it's Tuesday
- If it doesn't add value
- If it's an argumentative comment
- If it's superfluous

Don't feel bad about your comments being removed. It happens.  It's not a reflection on you. I kept other comments around because they add value to the post and would be useful for future visitors.

Comment: Thanks, for this screen shot, but your screen shot is pointless did you know why? its because pointless!!! is that a good comment?! while I am able to improve, to edit, to change your answer, or at least I can suggest to you to correct bad ideas, not saying that your answer is pointless!!! is that fair?

Comment: @Akam - is that supposed to be some sort of scientific argument?

Comment: @Akam It seems you didn't read past the first sentence of the first two undeleted comments, in which they followed up a subjective opinion about your answer (by itself rather useless) with detailed reasoning explaining the problems with your answer that lead to that opinion (which are highly valuable).  If you disagree with an answer's premise you should *not* be editing it to change it's meaning entirely; that is an inappropriate edit.  The appropriate course of action is to downvote (optionally) and explain, in a comment, the problem(s) you have with the answer.

Comment: @RichardTingle: yes, I am just simulating that words there, to bring George attention about (pointless words) that used in that comment for my answer, while the user can suggest in good way, In constructive way, such as: please correct these points, do more research on these, or any good way.

Comment: @Akam I see, try not to imitate people if possible. Its rarely considered polite. If you ask yourself, though, what do you think your deleted comments added to the question?

Answer (score 13):

What was that comment adding to the question or your answer?

Nothing.

So... it was removed. If it is adding nothing, why have it there?

---

And it wasn't just your comment. Other comments, by others were also removed, as they had nothing to do with the question or answer.

Comment: what about "I always had a suspicion that those OWASP guys are just a bunch of nothings"! I am really afraid that I applied most of OWASP guides! I am

Comment: @Akam - guess that wasn't flagged at the time. It is now gone. Happy?

Comment: @Oded - I don't think he was saying they added nothing, I think he was saying that future comments that referenced his removed comments lost their weight, because they no longer had a point of reference.

Comment: @JohnnyBones They were kept around because their reference to his comments were tangential, and they had substantial information on their own.  If I had even thought they would be irrelevant, I would have deleted them.

Answer (score 0):

Life ain't fair.  StackExchange is not a public entity, they can administer the site as they see fit.  If your comments were deemed offensive, annoying or inconsequential, they can be removed at any time by any moderator or representative of the site.  Have a look at the [ToS](https://stackexchange.com/legal).

Comment: "Life isn't fair" brings back all the childhood rage of 10 year old me. And temporarily earned you a downvote. You'll be glad to hear that 26 year old me vetoed that after regaining control

Comment: Which manifested in a downvote; the SE equivalent of a kick in the shin.  OWCH!  :oP