# In 10k tools, show posts that are automatically deleted when a user's account is deleted

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, 10k-tools, deleted-accounts

According to point 11 of [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/300411) negatively voted posts are automatically deleted when a user's account is deleted:

> The system will automatically delete any question (and its answers) or answer with a negative score when its owner's account is deleted, unless the question is open and has at least one positively-scored answer.

This is a better process than existed previously, prior to [partial implementation of this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199860/300411), but even so, there is still value in listing these deleted questions and answers on the moderation (10k) tools page.

Right now, these deleted posts do not appear anywhere I can see.  On my home site, a user quit about an hour ago, and I can see one of his deleted posts thanks to having 10k rep.  It shows that it was deleted by "Community," but it is not listed in the "recently deleted" section of my 10k tools page.

I suspect that this user had a number of downvoted questions and answers, and I would like to review them to ensure that nothing of value was lost when they were deleted.  I could then vote to undelete and/or flag moderators in specific instances to restore lost content.  But without such posts appearing in my list, I have no way of doing this.

Comment: Related a bit ago from Programmers.SE: [What roomba script went after this question](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6820/40980). I'm fairly sure that this was brought up on MSE, but it was probably in a comment.

Comment: @MichaelT Check the comments on the answer in that second linked post :)

Comment: I'm fairly sure I mentioned it somewhere else... which was where I was looking for it because I didn't recall posting that one.

Answer (score 3):

Given that the restriction is in place so that the list won't get overwhelmed when a user account is removed, what if we just added answers to the closed low-scored questions that exceeded some positive score threshold to the queue?

That way the community could see whether there is content that should be "rescued" from the questions that get removed during an account deletion, without it being likely that the list would overflow from a single event.

A common reason for "rage quitting" on ELL is that a user's questions are getting regularly put on hold for improvements. Often someone will write a answer that would be useful to other readers if the question were undeleted, improved and reopened, and it's a shame to lose those.

Comment: Congrats on 10K here, BTW!

Comment: @Ollie Thanks! It may have happened a bit sooner if I could have laid off the bounties ;) I've had access to the 10k tools on ELL for a while, but sometimes I forget they're there.

Comment: I [see what you mean](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315445/dont-show-hidden-communities-on-top-posts-in-network-profile)... not the best way to get attention, IMO.