# Don't show hidden communities on "Top Posts" in network profile

Tags: feature-request, network-profile, privacy, hidden-communities

I love the "Hide Communities" feature. Its official definition is (emphasis mine):

> Hiding a community means other users **will not see it in your** Communities list or **Top Network Posts**.

The "Communities list" part works, but the "Top Network Posts" can be interpreted in two ways; the widget visible on each [site profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/140933/nicolas-raoul?tab=profile) (where they're hidden) and the ['top' tab of the network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/80211/nicolas-raoul?tab=top) (where they aren't). Please hide them there as well.

## Demonstration

I have Worldbuilding as "hidden" in my Settings' "Hide Communities":

[image]

... but it still shows up in [my Top Network Posts](https://stackexchange.com/users/80211/nicolas-raoul) page, even when not logged in:

[image: a post from Worldbuilding in the Top Network Posts list]

Note: Not a duplicate; actually the only answerer there [asked me to post this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299234/why-are-my-hidden-communities-visible-under-the-top-reputation-and-activit#comment1033831_299235). Also note that while the existing bug report was marked as by design, this is a feature request to change the design.

Answer (score 5):

Behavior that exposes hidden communities has been complained about as a bug many times over the years. Some issues have been addressed, and some are "by design". Even if this particular request doesn't gain any traction, I think there is some support for either making the "Hide Community" feature more robust, or for expressing its limitations more clearly.

Here's an (incomplete) list just to illustrate:

[Top posts taken from hidden communities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277279/273494)

[Why are my hidden communities visible under the 'top', 'reputation' and 'activity' tabs on the Network Profile page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299234/273494)

[Text in Hide Communities page is misleading](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359659/273494)

["Hidden Profiles" still shown in Network Profile Top Posts list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/352899/273494)

[Aren't you exposing our hidden communities when we earn hats on those communities?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340766/273494)

[Hidden profiles are not hidden at all](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253599/273494)

[Reputation still showing for hidden communities on network profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324439/273494)