# Aren't you exposing our hidden communities when we earn hats on those communities?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-declined, winter-bash, hidden-communities

Aren't you exposing our hidden communities when we earn hats on those communities?

If everybody can see where we earn those hats, then so they will know about out hidden communities, no?

Or since they are hidden, then the hats that we have earned there, won't show off?

**Edit**

Seems like indeed your hidden communities are visible!

Could mods or someone fix this bug please?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Well I can see you've earned your current hat on two sites besides MSE, which aren't shown in your communities list. Looks like a bit of a data leak, although I can't see your name/profile on those sites (only that you're on them).

Comment: Hidden communities aren't really hidden, anyway - mods can always see them, and anyone can find them if they know where to look. Don't rely on them for privacy.

Comment: There's hidden and there's hidden. Given that anyone with remedial SQL skills can figure out your "hidden communities", and you don't even have to be a mod to do so, this seems not that big of a deal. [Accidentally jinxed @ArtOfCode]

Comment: @tchrist to me, it seems a bit like an unintentional doxxing. Sure, the information is technically publicly available, but now it's being shown in a passively-accessible way.

Comment: @TheWanderer I totally agree with you

Comment: You don't even need SQL skills in many cases, @tchrist

Answer (score 20):

I don’t think that this is a bug.

If you go to your community settings page, it says:

> Hiding a community means other users will not see it in your Communities list or Top Network Posts. **It does not, however, mean your activity is private.**

I consider earning/wearing hats as an "activity".

Hiding a community will only hide it from your public lists, but all activity is still public (including earning hats).

Comment: That's right. The feature is misnamed: it's _only_ for the list on your profile. "Unlisted" would be better, so that people who aren't paying any attention don't think they're getting privacy...