# "Hidden Profiles" still shown in Network Profile Top Posts list

Tags: bug, network-profile, privacy, hidden-communities

I just noticed that although the hidden profiles are hidden in the "Accounts" tab on the Network profile, top questions from hidden profiles are still shown under the "Top" tab (and other tabs).

This cannot possibly be by design, right?