# Is it possible to view the markdown source of a deleted question that I answered?

Tags: support, markdown, deleted-questions

Recently, a question and my answer to it has been deleted because the user asking the question had their account deleted and the post received a negative score. While the question had some flaws, I really liked my answer and wish to preserve it (and therefore the question as well!).

For my deleted answer, I could simply copy the source by editing. But for the deleted *question*, the edit and revision history options don't work. (I can still see the HTML output via recently deleted questions, though.)

Is there some way I can retrieve the question Markdown source? (Preferably within my privilege range; the question concerns [CS.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com))

If I'm personally unable to do this, would a mod or privileged user be able to do this if I asked?

Comment: Related: [A question should not be deleted by the user deletion algorithm if it has upvoted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199860/a-question-should-not-be-deleted-by-the-user-deletion-algorithm-if-it-has-upvote)

Comment: Note that the deletion of the question and answer pair were re-evaluated by the mod that has done the deletion and have been restored. So, my current problem has been resolved, but I think that an answer to this question could help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes as short as you can see the question, but with the only exception (that I can tell for now) being you don't have the "moderator tools" privilege and you have an answer under it.

So before you reach the required rep for "moderator tools", you can only ask a mod or someone else able to see it. They can fetch the MD source using the "source" link in the revision history and send it to you.

You can see the users on CS.SE sorting by reputation [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all). The recommended way is to drop into a chatroom and ask someone.

Comment: I was kinda certain the sub 10K, own deleted question view and the meta-mod/10k view were the same.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I didn't understand what you mean.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek But this question concerns view one's own answer to the deleted question of _another_ user.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek And while the basic view may be the same, the 'edit history' and 'edit' options on the question 404'd (while the question was still deleted)